# disable click outside dismiss on a material 3 jetpack compose ModalBottomSheet

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3, jetpack-compose-modalbottomsheet

is there any way i can disable this built in behaviour of dissmissal of the Material 3 bottomsheet after any click outside the half expanded bottom sheet

```
   ModalBottomSheet(
    onDismissRequest = { },// i'd like to ignore this property,handle dissmissal myself
    sheetState = bottomSheetState,
    tonalElevation = MagicUnit.mu025,
    dragHandle = {},
)
```

is there any suggestion to apply ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `confirmValueChange` parameter for more control or disabling it.

```
ModalBottomSheet(
    onDismissRequest = { /*Do nothing*/ },
    sheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState(
        confirmValueChange = { 
            if (condition) true else false
        }
    ),
) { /* content */}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about ModalBottomSheet composable but in BottomSheetScaffold there is a parameter flag named sheetGesturesEnabled we can toggle it to false to disable the user actions outside of the BottomSheet